# How to save .wav files together in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, join, concatenation, wav

I need to join two `.wav` files into a new `.wav`.

E.g. I need to join `a.wav` and `b.wav` to make `ab.wav`.

But these files are not the same length, which generates this error:

```
Error using vertcat
Dimensions of matrices being concatenated are not consistent.

Error in twoSounds (line 21)
samples = [snd ; snd2]
```

And here is a few bits from my code itself...

```
s1 = 'a.wav';
s2 = 'b.wav';

[snd, fs, bits] = wavread(s1);
[snd2, fs, bits] = wavread(s2);

START = 1;
END = size(snd);
END2 = size(snd2);

sample1 = snd(START:END);
sample2 = snd2(START:END2);
samples = [sample1 ; sample2]
```

Comment: What does `size(snd)` and `size(snd2)` tell you?

Comment: You should give the sizes. Try `samples = [snd snd2];`

Comment: Different lenghts should not be a problem. Maybe one file is stereo and the other is mono?

Comment: size(snd) tells me the end of the wav file.

Comment: samples = [snd snd2]; gives the same problem.

Comment: How would I check for stereo/mono Luis?

Comment: what sizes are `snd` and `snd2`?? `1000x2`? `500x3`?

Comment: snd is 598528x1 and snd2 is 324864x2

Comment: try using one channel of `snd2` like `sample = [snd ; snd(:,1)];`. I don't know the optimal solution.

Comment: Yes that worked! Top marks Kamtal! I notice a slight change between using ...(:,1) and (:,2) but same sound and working so great.

Comment: @Kamtal, I suggest you add that as an answer, so that the question appears solved at the front page (instead of the capital "SOLVED" in the title.) If an answer is not provided either by you or OP I don't think this question adds much value to the site and should therefore IMHO be removed. BUT, it should _definitely not_ be deleted if a valid answer is given. To OP, you may also answer your own question, but maybe Kamtal deserves an accepted answer for helping you out =) Anyhow, that's your call... Also, I edited the title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `snd` is mono with size of `598528x1`,

and `snd2` is stereo with size of `324864x2`,

Your best choice is

```
sample = [snd ; mean(snd2,2)];
```

Comment: Hehe, the answer and my comment were posted 3 seconds apart! +1 for  posting it as an answer =)